# How do I change only the home url of logo on a wordpress site with oceanWP theme?

Tags: html, angular, wordpress

I have a site deployed on say, abc.com which uses angular for homepage and WordPress for the blogs. I have deployed the WordPress website in a subfolder inside abc.com. The file structure is as depicted in the image below.

Now I want to change only the homepage link on the logo of the WordPress website, which on click will redirect us to abc.com. Rest of the blog links will work normally, say 'abc.com/myProj/blog-detail'

[File structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTuPB.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OceanWP uses the [`the_custom_logo()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_custom_logo/) function to display your custom logo and link to the WordPress site’s home page (example.com/myProj). The file that renders the logo is located at `/wp-content/themes/oceanwp/partials/header/logo.php`.

You can use the [`get_custom_logo`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_custom_logo/) hook to modify the HTML of the custom logo and change the link to point to the actual home page (example.com).

To do that, you’ll have to create a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) (or a plugin) and insert the following in your `functions.php` file:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Modify the logo link
 *
 * @param string $html  Custom logo HTML output
 * @param int $blog_id  ID of the blog to get the custom logo for
 * @return string       Custom logo HTML output with modified link
 */
function oceanwp_child_modify_logo_link( $html, $blog_id ) {
  $custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
  $html = sprintf(
    '<a href="%1$s" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home">%2$s</a>',
    esc_url( 'https://example.com/' ),  // modify the link here
    wp_get_attachment_image( $custom_logo_id, 'full', false, $custom_logo_attr )
  );

  return $html;
}

add_filter( 'get_custom_logo', 'oceanwp_child_modify_logo_link', 10, 2 );
```

If you also need to handle things like the logo alt attribute being empty or the logo not being set, you can refer to the [`get_custom_logo()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_custom_logo/) function.

(I’ve tested it on WordPress 5.3.2 and OceanWP 1.7.4)

Comment: I am adding the code in the child theme's functions.php and after saving the file the code vanishes after some seconds! What is this bug in wordpress?

Comment: This did not work on my ocean wp theme. Whatever I saved in the child theme's function.php vanished after moments of saving it. I had to create a custom header and added a link to the logo manually. Thanks for help!